Find URLs in with Regex with SSJS
I am on a mission to extract URLs from all the emails unfortunately I am getting stuck on regex with SSJS.
My plan is to call the Content Builder API (/asset/v1/content/assets?$filter=id=12345)for the email HTML. Then use regex against the result to find all the URLs. I am able to stringify print the result so the API call is good. However, the regex code threw Error 500 when I run it in Cloudpages: const reg = /href=\\"(\S+)\\"\s/;
I have also tried
(?:\shref=\\")(\S+)(?:\\"\s)
I have tested both of these on Regex101.
Appreciate if someone can point out what I am doing wrong or if there are other options to extract a list of URLs from all the emails in the system. Thanks.
Here are sample of how the URLs would look like
<a href=\"https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/">Stack Exchange</a>
<a data-linkto=\"https://\" href=\"mailto:email@me.net\">Email us</a>
<a data-linkto=\"other\" href=\"%%=RedirectTo(@URL)=%%\">
<a data-linkto=\"https://\" href=\"https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf\" s>click here</a>


May take some experimenting with the escaped double-quotes in your API response, but you could do something like this to find the matches:
<script runat="server" language="javascript">

Platform.Load("core","1");

var str = '<a href=\"https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/">Stack Exchange</a>'
str += '<a data-linkto=\"https://\" href=\"mailto:email@me.net\">Email us</a>'
str += '<a data-linkto=\"other\" href=\"%%=RedirectTo(@URL)=%%\">'
str += '<a data-linkto=\"https://\" href=\"https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf\" s>click here</a>'

Write(str.replace(/</g,"&lt;"));

var regex = /href=\"(.*?)\"/g;

var matches = str.match(regex);

Write("<hr>" + Stringify(matches))

</script>

Output:
["href=\"https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/\"", "https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/", "href=\"mailto:email@me.net\"", "mailto:email@me.net", "href=\"%%=RedirectTo(@URL)=%%\"", "%%=RedirectTo(@URL)=%%", "href=\"https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf\"", "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"]

Try it yourself: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/fjSjeGNA
Side note: Parsing HTML with RegEx is rough. So many exceptions and nuances.  I'd prepare to babysit the code.

Thanks Adam. I agreed with your last line so I marked it as answer!  I found the error was due to I declared the reg as "const". I changed it to "var" and it's running now, but it gives me two lines for the same url - like
" href=\"https://sample.com/\" ",
"https://https://sample.com/".
I guess it's good enough for what I wanted to do. Thank you so much.

I would like to share another regex pattern I made for the sample response html you described above:
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var str = '<a href=\"https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/">Stack Exchange</a>'
str += '<a data-linkto=\"https://\" href=\"mailto:email@me.net\">Email us</a>'
str += '<a data-linkto=\"other\" href=\"%%=RedirectTo(@URL)=%%\">'
str += '<a data-linkto=\"https://\" href=\"https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf\" s>click here</a>'

var regex = /(?<=href=\").*?(?=\/?\")/g;
var matches = str.match(regex);

Write(Stringify(matches));

</script>

Output
["https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/", "mailto:email@me.net", "%%=RedirectTo(@URL)=%%", "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"]

